# What is an Equilateral Ellipse

Tags: geometry

I did and exam a while ago and one of the questions asked to find a formula for an "equilateral ellipse". In my mind an equilateral ellipse should be a circle, but it seems I am wrong.

I searched online for the term, but didn't find anything useful. Does anyone know what it is, can find a formula and give me some references?

Thanks,
Douglas.

Comment: Why do you think that it is **not** a circle?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about pure mathematics.

Comment: This expression is not used. If it was, it would indeed be for a circle (in the sense of equality of the axis).

Comment: @Marco13 I was not given any points for that question and, due to the nature of the test, I don't have access to the test official answers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe an "equilateral ellipse" is a circle, as you suspected.
Or at least that is old terminology:

[image: EqEll]

> Coleman, Percy. *Co-ordinate geometry: An elementary course*. Clarendon Press, 1914.

Comment: Thanks. I have found some other references on the internet, and they are all pretty old. As you said, it is probably just an old terminology.